# Switch color scheme in R shiny based on input

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I got into R shiny today and spent the last 10 hours straight building a nice shiny webmap with leaflet integration...most things work out so far! (yay holidays) But I have an issue with a conditional selection of variables.

Users are able to select a political party whose election results are shown as colored polygons on a map. Based on the user's party selection, the color scheme should change accordingly. E.g. user selects party 1, color scheme should be flaged as 'Blues', party 2 as 'Greys' etc.

In the leaflet part I define the color scheme this way:

```
leafletProxy("austriaMap") %>%
    addPolygons(data = data1(), color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
                fillColor = ~colorQuantile("Greys", data2())(data2()),
                highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                                    bringToFront = TRUE)
                )
```

This works perfectly, but I want the "Greys" part to be switched based on the selected party. I tried the `switch` function to select from a list of colors based on user input:

```
  col.list <- list("OrRd", "Greys", "Blues")

  cols <- reactive({
    switch(input$party,
           "party1" = col.list[[1]],
           "party2" = col.list[[2]],
           "party3" = col.list[[3]])
  })
```

Which should result in `cols` holding the appropriate string. However, when I put this string in the leaflet code, I get this error message:

```
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'toPaletteFunc' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive')"
```

Any idea? This is, albeit its apparent simplicity, the most time consuming part so far. It's really strange, because if I put the string in the leaflet part manually, everything works. If I place the string by invoking `cols`, I receive this error. Any other solutions? Thank you!

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `cols` in your `leaflet` call? Are you calling it as `cols`, or as `cols()`?

Comment: Not a reproducible example, please edit so other folks can copy/paste and actually run and reproduce the error message, without that it's skilled guesswork.

Comment: @Phil: Call me donkey...4 hours searching and it was really just cols() instead of just cols. Thank you.